# How to solve object detection problem containing some static objects with no variation?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, object-detection, faster-rcnn

[image]I am working with a object detection problem, here i am using Region based convolution neural network to detect and segment objects in an image.

I have 8 objects to be segmented(Android App Icons), 6 of them posses variations in background and rest 2 will be under white background(static).

I have already taken 200 variations of each object and trained on MaskRCNN, my model is able to depict the patterns very well in 6 objects with variation.But on rest 2 objects it's struggling even on train set even though it's a exact match.

Q. If i have n objects with variations and m objects with no variation(static), do i need to oversample it? Shall i use any other technique here in this case?

Here in image, icons in black bounding boxes are prominent to change(based on background and there position w.r.t background) but Icon in green bounding box will not have any variations(always be in white background)

I have tried adding more images containing static objects but no luck, Can anyone suggest how to go about in any such problem? I don't want to use sliding window(static image processing) approach here.

Comment: can you share example of no variations images ?

Comment: Hi @Suman, I have updated my post with image.